# VideoView isn't showing in ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, video

I'm making a ListView of videos, so I decided to use video view. I know it's encouraged to use TextureViews to display the videos rather than VideoView, but I think VideoView should work fine for me. The problem is my videos aren't showing up. I know my video paths are fine because if I hardcode the file paths into a videoview *outside* of the listview then it shows up just fine. Also, if I add the video paths to textviews instead of videoviews in the listview then it displays them just fine. The problem is solely with videoviews. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class VideoListFragment extends Fragment {

    private Activity currentActivity;
    private long projectId;
    VideoAdapter videoAdapter;
    List<String> videoPathList;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list, container, false);

        currentActivity = getActivity();
        projectId = ((Project)currentActivity).projectId;

        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

        ListView videoList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoList);
        File directory = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + projectId + File.separator);
        File[] dirContentsList = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                return filename.endsWith(".mp4");
            }
        });

        Pair[] pairs = new Pair[dirContentsList.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dirContentsList.length; i++)
            pairs[i] = new Pair(dirContentsList[i]);

        // Sort them by timestamp.
        Arrays.sort(pairs);

        // Take the sorted pairs and extract only the file part, discarding the timestamp.
        for (int i = 0; i < dirContentsList.length; i++)
            newList.add(pairs[i].filePath);

        videoPathList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(Arrays.toString(dirContentsList).split(",")));
        videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.video_list, newList);
        videoList.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
        videoAdapter.addAll(newList);
        videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return rootView;
    }

    private class VideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public VideoAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> videos) {
            super(context, resource, videos);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if  (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.video_row, null);
                holder.videoView = (VideoView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            String videoPath = getItem(position);
            holder.videoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public VideoView videoView;
    }

    class Pair implements Comparable {
        public long t;
        public File f;
        public String filePath;

        public Pair(File file) {
            f = file;
            t = file.lastModified();
            filePath = file.getPath();
        }

        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            long u = ((Pair) o).t;
            return t < u ? -1 : t == u ? 0 : 1;
        }
    };
}
```

video_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoList"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

video_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VideoView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
```

View Tree

```
android.widget.RelativeLayout{d0fdaf6 V.E..... ... -1440,0-0,2463}
                      android.widget.ListView{c76c3fb VFED.VC. F.. 0,0-1440,28 #7f0c009b app:id/videoList}
                        android.widget.VideoView{d6a1c18 VFE..... ... 0,0-1440,0 #7f0c0099 app:id/videoView}
                        android.widget.VideoView{d4d7671 VFE..... ... 0,4-1440,4 #7f0c0099 app:id/videoView}
                        android.widget.VideoView{780c56 VFE..... ... 0,8-1440,8 #7f0c0099 app:id/videoView}
                        android.widget.VideoView{763a4d7 VFE..... ... 0,12-1440,12 #7f0c0099 app:id/videoView}
                        android.widget.VideoView{6f0e1c4 VFE..... ... 0,16-1440,16 #7f0c0099 app:id/videoView}
                        android.widget.VideoView{af208ad VFE..... ... 0,20-1440,20 #7f0c0099 app:id/videoView}
                        android.widget.VideoView{a8097e2 VFE..... ... 0,24-1440,24 #7f0c0099 app:id/videoView}
```

Comment: so why dont you use `TextureViews` instead of `VideoViews`? its usage is pretty much the same

Comment: I think I'll do that eventually, but I wanted to know what the problem is now, because I'm assuming if I don't fix this problem now, I'll have the same issue when I convert it to a TextureView.

Comment: ok, you are only calling `setVideoPath` on your `videoView` and not `start()`ing it, what should it display then? (i can be wrong here though since i worked with `VideoView` couple of years back...)

Comment: That's not the problem. Because if you don't call start() the VideoView is atleast black, but for me, it's just not there. (Also, I tried calling start() and it didn't help)

Comment: run `adb shell dumpsys activity top` and see your view tree, note the `VideoView`s bounds

Comment: What does this tell me?

Comment: you will see the dump of your listview items

Comment: Yeah it has all the videoviews listed in it.

Comment: did you notice their bounds? what are they?

Comment: I've never used this so if you could help me out with what I should be looking for that'd be great. I added it to the question.

Comment: stuff like 0,12-1440,12 its left,  top,  right,  bottom

Comment: Yeah so I see that, and I added what I got from the command to the question so you could see too, but I don't know what to do with this information.